# Time Machine like folder backups for Ubuntu

Tags: backup

Hey guys I have an interesting backup situation that I can't seem to find a program that matches my needs online so I came here to see if you guys knew anything.

I would like a program that

- Backs up a folder once every hour for a day
- Keeps daily backups (which would be the last hour of a day) for a month
- Keeps archived (zipped tar'd or whatever compression) monthly backups (which would be the last day in a month) for a year

and it would ultimately store them all in one folder.  Any suggestions or config files for existing programs that would match this?

Answer (score 2):

the website of timeshift suggests `back-in-time` to solve your problem. You can find the project at http://backintime.le-web.org/

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of Timeshift but I've never tried it. Might be something to look into. http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html

Comment: That's exactly what I'd want but I want to backup an external drive as well and TimeShift only allows for backups of the main system

Comment: The timeshift website suggests backintime to backup user data: http://backintime.le-web.org/ perhaps you can achieve your goal with that tool?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann That works perfectly, thank you!  If you add it as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

Create your own script for backup.

Schedule your jobs for backup, etc.. using [crontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/crontab.5.html)